# One computer on one particular wireless = massive packet loss to no connection beyond the router

Tags: wireless-networking

This is a bizarre one and any help will be greatly appreciated. I have a work laptop which has worked fine both at home, work and out and about for several years. About 2 weeks ago though, it stopped wirelessly connecting to the internet at home. All other devices at home are unaffected (which lead me to believe it was the computer). Wired works fine. Tried changing IPs, disabling firewalls etc...

Took the laptop into work and everything is fine. Now thinking it's the home connection somehow.

Done a factory reset on wireless router. Rebuilt the laptop. Totally clean on both. The problem still persists. It's just the one laptop on that specific connection when done over wireless.

For reference, it's not that there is no connection it's just that there is about 95% packet loss and when one does get through the time is about 3000ms. Have tried different channels and used scanners to check that the new channels are clear.

Any advice on where to go from here?

Chris.

Comment: How are you testing when you measure 95% packet loss? Are you pinging the router's LAN IP?

Comment: Nope, I'm Google pinging.

Comment: Don't do that. You're testing a whole bunch of things at once.

Comment: FYI. Ping to the router was fine. Only beyond was the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the answer although I don't understand why it's the answer. Forcing the network card to use 802.11b has resolved the issue.

Comment: No, don't do that. It will slow down the entire network. Every single transmission from every single device in the network, including the access point, now has to be prefixed with an 802.11b sequence to tell that one device not to transmit on top of the 802.11g/n transmission.

Comment: I'll play with other setting tomorrow night. Curious as to how it fixed the problem though.

Comment: Hi All, for some reason 'n' isn't listed. I've tested the following. a = general failure. b = fixed and fine. g = the problem I've explained. Combinations involving a = general failure. Combination involving g (and not a) = the problem occurs.